# LD_LIBRARY_PATH unset by screen

Tags: bash, environment-variables, gnu-screen

Running `screen` in bash wipes the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I've done some reading and it seems that this is expected behaviour, but I need to get around it.

The workaround is adding the LD_LIBRARY_PATH declaration to `~/.bashrc`. In my case, LD_LIBRARY_PATH gets changed a lot between the launch of the shell and when I invoke screen, so I need to get the *current* value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH into the `screen` session.

Comment: you have export LD_KLIBRARY_PATH before run screen?

Comment: Superuser question.

Comment: Sorry, can I somehow move it over, or should I delete and repost?

Comment: If you get five close votes, it will be bumped there automatically. One more to go!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`screen` doesn't unset the environment variable; it is removed by Linux itself.

On most systems, the `/usr/bin/screen` executable is installed with the *setgid* bit for `utmp` group, in order to be able to modify the `utmp` database. It also uses *setgid* to control access to the socket directory (`/var/run/screen/`).

On Linux, when a *setuid* (or *setgid*) program is ran, it does not receive certain environment variables (including `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, several other `LD_*` variables, and `HOSTALIASES`), in order to reduce the possible attack points: Otherwise you could write a small library and trick `su` or `sudo` into calling your "improved" functions that way.

---

You can remove the *setgid* bit from `screen`, but you will have to make the socket directory fully accessible by everyone (mode 0777). It shouldn't be a security risk, though, as `screen` also checks the attacher's UID itself.

However, you should *not* make the `utmp` database world-writable.

Comment: (Note: I am not quite sure whether the environment variables are removed by the kernel, or by ld-linux.so, or by glibc runtime.)

Comment: Worked really fine. These are the commands that need to be done: `chgrp root $(which screen)` and `chmod 777 /var/run/screen`. You can test with this small bash script: `while true; do echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH; sleep 2; done`  You will see that the path is successfully displayed. Thanks grawity.

Answer (score 8):

In your `.screenrc`, you can use the `setenv` command to set a value in screen's environment.

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH_SCREEN
```

This is set before your shell is started. Obviously `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_SCREEN` needs to be set before you start screen.

Comment: See grawity's answer -- LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a special variable in this context. Even if this worked (setenv doesn't need to '=', btw) it wouldn't be very helpful to rename the environment variable we're trying to set; programs would still be looking at the canonical name (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974069/setting-environment-variables-in-screenrc).

Comment: Than's for the correction. I fixed the syntax and had forgotten that I had a different variable in the environment starting screen. The `_SCREEN` one can be set in your rc file or in a wrapper script that starts screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try `export`ing the environment variable you are interested in.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to keep the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable is to run a command inside `screen` as follows:

```bash
screen -dmLS compile bash -lc "make -j12"
```